# How do I achieve this "Out of Sync"/mis-registration fill style in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, fill

What is an easy way to achieve this "Out of Sync" Color Fill style?

[image]

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS6 and I think there is an easy way to do this with the way Illustrator is set up, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Fill in `Layer 1`, Lines in `Layer 2`. **1.** Select everything in one of the layers. **2.** Nudge it with arrow keys. **3.** Wait for your client to ask you: "Why is this off?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make things easy for yourself when editing later, it pays off to do a bit more work upfront by using the `Appearance` panel for this.

1. Draw a shape
2. Give it any fill and no stroke
3. Open the `Appearance` panel
4. Select your shape with the Move tool (<kbd>V</kbd>)
5. Choose `Add New Stroke`, either through `Appearance` panel options
   or with the icon bottom leftmost on the panel
6. Give the new stroke the desired colour and weight in the
   `Appearance` panel
7. With the stroke still selected in the panel, choose `Effect >
   Distort & Transform > Transform...` and use the `Move` settings to
   change the stroke's position. Click `OK`.

This way, the stroke and the fill are both controlled by the same shape. If you alter the shape in any way, both fill and stroke will change accordingly. This saves you the burden of having to make the exact same changes to a shape twice.

As an added bonus, you can drag the shape into the `Graphic Styles` panel to store its settings later. If you select another shape and then click the graphic style, it will change its appearance to the style. Saves you the time to reproduce the exact same transformation over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Color your artwork without borders
2. Copy artwork
3. Delete fill of copied artwork, add border
4. shift copy left/right according to taste

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any preference set-up to achieve the out of register look but simply 'copy' the object with the stroke and fill, then 'paste in front', then nudge it until it is the desired distance apart, remove the stroke from the lower layer, then remove the fill in the layer above.

Set the stroke to 'overprint' or else it may 'knock-out'.

Perhaps that is what you have already done.