# What is this image effect (similar to viewing a 3d film without the glasses) called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If you look at this [site](http://xyz.xyz), the designer(s) made use of a an effect similar to what a 3d film would look like without the 3d glasses (if your remember those days). How would I replicate this effect in Photoshop for a photo?

Image reference:
[image: Earth with glasses-less 3d-effect]

Comment: Actually **it is** a 3D effect without the glasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3D effect is called [anaglyph 3D](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D). Though in this case ist is just simply a color channel offset. So it might also be simulating a mis-registration (see [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51389/please-help-how-to-do-off-registration-in-illustrator-cs6/51394#51394)).

What you do is you duplicate the artwork run a red filter on the other (multipy by red) offset that and then blue  (actually for full color cyan) filter the other copy. If you want a real effect you will need 2 images.